# CodedUITest failing because of Taskbar thumbnail blocking the control

Tags: coded-ui-tests

My codedui test get failed, when some of the control blocked by the taskbar thumbnail.
I have turned off the taskbar thumbnail.

Is there any other solution that we can do it programmatically by resizing the window or something?
Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The ApplicationUnderTest class has a property called maximized you can set to true:

```
var application = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(LAUNCH_LOCATION);
application.Maximized = true;
```

This will launch the application and then maximize it.